# Android Cannot Insert Data Into Azure SQL but It can insert data

Tags: sql, azure

I was trying to figure this out but I wasn't able to do it. I was trying to insert text into the Azure SQL using EditText in Android but I wasn't successful. I am able to pull the data from Azure SQL but I wasn't able to insert into Azure SQL database.

This is my code that I wrote to pull the data. I would be so happy if you could also provide the answer with a code

```
public class CheckLogin extends AsyncTask<String, String, String>{
    String z = "";
    Boolean isSuccess = false;
    String name1 = "";



    protected void onPreExecute(){
        dialog = new ProgressDialog(MainActivity.this);
        dialog.setTitle("Loading");
        dialog.setMessage("Loading");
        dialog.show();
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(String r) {
        dialog.dismiss();
        Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, r, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

        if(isSuccess){
            message.setText(name1);
        }
    }

    @Override
    protected String doInBackground(String... params) {
        try{
            con = connectionclass();
            if(con == null){
                z = "There is a problem. Cannot Connect Azure SQL Database";
            } else {
                String text = insert.getText().toString().trim();
                String query = "SELECT * FROM Users";
                Statement stmt = con.createStatement();
                ResultSet rs = stmt.executeQuery(query);
                if(rs.next()){
                    name1 = rs.getString("UserName");
                    z = "query successful";
                    isSuccess = true;
                    con.close();
                } else {
                    z = "Invalid Query";
                    isSuccess = false;
                }
            }
        } catch (Exception ex){
            isSuccess = false;
            z = ex.getMessage();

            Log.e("sql error", z);
        }

        return z;
    }

}

@SuppressLint("NewApi")
public Connection connectionclass(){
    StrictMode.ThreadPolicy policy = new StrictMode.ThreadPolicy.Builder().permitAll().build();
    StrictMode.setThreadPolicy(policy);
    Connection connection = null;
    String ConnectionURL = null;

    try{
        Class.forName("net.sourceforge.jtds.jdbc.Driver");
        ConnectionURL = "jdbc:jtds:sqlserver://chatmesql.database.windows.net:1433;DatabaseName=Testing;user=Furkan@chatmesql;password=xxxxxxxx;encrypt=true;trustServerCertificate=false;hostNameInCertificate=*.database.windows.net;loginTimeout=30;";
        connection = DriverManager.getConnection(ConnectionURL);
    } catch (SQLException se){
        Log.e("Error 1 here : " , se.getMessage());
    } catch (ClassNotFoundException e){
        Log.e("Error 2 here : ", e.getMessage());
    } catch (Exception e){
        Log.e("Error here 3 : ", e.getMessage());


    }

    return connection;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Furqan, can you confirm on the 'User Role' been set for the User (username in connection string) in Azure SQL ?

Most of thr time, if you have only Read access, you will not be able to make any changes in Azure SQL DB, rather in any Database in general.

Would advise you to check on role, have valid role of not, and then give a try.